# Java cannot be resolved to a variable or not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods

I'm reasonably new to Java and I'm making a little game that runs in the console.
I need to call this method if somebody wants to play again.

```
printGrid(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);
```

I have tried this below (where turn and newGame are declared as global variables:

```
private static void xWins(boolean turn, boolean newGame) {
    String playerChoice;
    System.out.println("Player X Wins!");
    System.out.println("|Would you like to play again? |");
    System.out.println("|Enter Y or N                  |");
        playerChoice = enterChoice(turn);
            switch(playerChoice){
            case "n": thankYou();break;
            case "N": thankYou();break;
            case "no": thankYou(); break;
            case "No": thankYou();break;
            case "NO": thankYou();break;
            case "nO": thankYou();break;
            default: turn = true; newGame = true;
            }
}
```

I tried to make it work with this, which goes with this in the main loop

`if (newGame == true) printGrid(A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3);`

The error message I am getting in Eclipse is

```
The method xWins(boolean, boolean) in the type ticTacToe is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)
```

Otherwise, if I try to call `printGrid` directly instead of `newGame = true;` at the end of the class then I get messages telling me that each of these globally defined variables cannot be resolved to a variable. Making this a public class also makes no difference. After looking on StackOverflow for similar answers I am still clueless.

Comment: How are you calling `xWins`?

Comment: The error message is telling you that your method expects to receive *two* boolean arguments when you call it, but you're only giving it one. Method arguments aren't optional in Java, if your signature expects it, you *must* provide it.

Comment: Why do you use a switch case? A simple if/else statement would be much easier. Also look into String.equalsIgnoreCase(). You could replace all of the case statements with one statement saying `if (playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") || playerChocie.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {...}`. The `turn = true` and `newGame = true` statements would then go in the else block

Comment: Thank you, I'll try using the if else statement.

Comment: @Maroun Exactly, it was an error in how I was calling it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method xWins is looking for two boolean parameters. You do not show us how you call that method, but by the error it is obvious that you are only trying to pass it one boolean value. Since a method by that name doesn't exist that accepts only one parameter, it can't continue--The method you created that is looking for two booleans as parameters won't work if you only try to pass it one.

Comment: This is a link to the whole thing (without the printGrid being called at the start of a new game): 
https://gist.github.com/SarahJessica/e75facaf5637b6c7fe2b
It is a lot to look through TBH. :/

Comment: Look at lines 84 and 91 - You're only passing it one boolean. You should also pass it your "newGame" variable. Either that or remove the second boolean parameter from the method declaration, but that only works if you don't plan to use "newGame" within xWins()

Comment: From what I see you don't need to pass "newGame" into the method, so I would take it out of the declaration and only use `private static void xWins(boolean turn) {...}`

Comment: Thank you so much. That appears to be the problem solved. 
I'm embarrassed because this was such an obvious oversight!
Many, many thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries! Glad we could help!